# How quotation marks in .env files are parsed?

Tags: environment-variables

There seem to be [only three rules](https://smartmob-rfc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2-dotenv.html) about parsing the .env files: (1) they need to be encoded in UTF-8, (2) comment lines start with `#`, and (3) the format is `VAR=VAL`. But how quotation marks are parsed? Bash has it's specific rules for them, but .env are not Bash. I also found that [Docker takes the quotation marks as-is](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/). On another hand, I saw .env files using quotation marks.

Are there any formal rules? Should quotation marks be avoided in .env files, or when shouldn't they?

Comment: I don't think there's a general set of rules for .env files (apart from the ones you mentioned), if you specify a framework, like Laravel or Node, each use libraries to read them, and each library has it's own ways of reading the file, the only way to know if the quotation marks are taken as-is, is to read the documentation or trial-error.

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro this is what I did, just looking for a confirmation if I missed something, or there is no rules.